# Write a function that returns random int

Tags: c

I write a function that returns a random `int` between 1 and 6. But when I call this function in `main`, it gives same number. Where's the problem?

```
int count, diceRoll;
srand(time(NULL));

for (count = 0; count < 6; count++) {
    diceRoll = (rand() % 6) + 1;
    return diceRoll;
}
```

Comment: Use `srand()` only once in the program, preferably soon after `main() {`. `rand()` is pseudo random generator, but  for a given seed it repeats same sequence.

Comment: `return diceRoll;` unconditionally inside the loop kinda makes the loop pointless don't you think? `srand(time(NULL));` should only be called once, generally in `main` at the beginning of your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function has multiple problems:

- the prototype is missing
- you reinitialize the pseudo random number generator from the current time at each call, hence you get the same value for `rand()` until the time changes, which takes one full second.
- the `for` loop is useless as you always return the value of `diceRoll` inside its body.

You should initialize the PRNG once at the beginning of the program and use:

```
int rand6(void) {
    return 1 + rand() % 6;
}
```

There is a very small bias in this function as the number of possibilities for `rand()` is not a multiple of `6`.